# Adding vertical space after header in LilyPond score

Tags: lilypond, engraving, lead-sheets

I have prepared a `\header` and I would like to increase the vertical space before my first stave, which also includes chords.

Is that also possible with LilyPond?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest approach would be to include a `\markup \vspace #1` command before your score block. You can change the `#1` to any value, including values with decimals.

```
\version "2.18.2"

\header {
  title = "This"
}

\markup \vspace #1 % change this value accordingly

sample = \relative c'' {
  c4
}

\score {
  \new Staff \sample
  \layout { }
}
```